# Sql Server 2008 Ambiguous and aggregate function Error

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select distinct (Member_Mailid), OrderLog_City, Member_MailId, 
       OrderLog_MovieName, OrderLog_MovieLanguage  
from tbl_OrderLog 
where 
OrderLog_Initiated between
  '2013-02-01 00:00:01.010' and '2013-02-01 23:59:59.990' 
and OrderLog_MovieLanguage in 
  ('TAMIL','ENGLISH','HINDI','MALAYALAM') 
group by Member_Mailid
having 
 count(Member_Mailid)>3  
order by member_mailid asc
```

When I run the above query, I face some errors.

I need the following columns in my result that's why I previously specified in the `select` statement:

```
(OrderLog_City,
Member_MailId,
OrderLog_MovieName,
OrderLog_MovieLanguage)
```

Which lists Customers who have watched More than 3 times and 5 times.

But it throws an error;

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column
>   'tbl_OrderLog.OrderLog_City' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.
>
> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Ambiguous column name
>   'member_mailid"

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`.

Since you're using `COUNT`, you need to aggregate with `GROUP BY`.

You need to include all the non-aggregate columns in `GROUP BY` clause.

Something like this should run successfully:

```
select Member_Mailid
  , OrderLog_City
  , OrderLog_MovieName
  , OrderLog_MovieLanguage
from tbl_OrderLog
where OrderLog_Initiated between '2013-02-01 00:00:01.010' and '2013-02-01 23:59:59.990'
  and OrderLog_MovieLanguage in ('TAMIL','ENGLISH','HINDI','MALAYALAM')
group by Member_Mailid
  , OrderLog_City
  , OrderLog_MovieName
  , OrderLog_MovieLanguage
having COUNT(Member_Mailid) > 3
order by member_mailid asc
```

**Edit after comment**

If you want to get distinct `Member_Mailid` values based on the above query, just turn into a sub-query and run a `DISTINCT` against it:

```
select distinct(Member_Mailid)
from
(
  select Member_Mailid
  from tbl_OrderLog
  where OrderLog_Initiated between '2013-02-01 00:00:01.010' and '2013-02-01 23:59:59.990'
    and OrderLog_MovieLanguage in ('TAMIL','ENGLISH','HINDI','MALAYALAM')
  group by Member_Mailid
    , OrderLog_City
    , OrderLog_MovieName
    , OrderLog_MovieLanguage
  having COUNT(Member_Mailid) > 3
) m
```

Comment: Thank You For Replying Mr.Preston, But Unfortunately i face one error named "Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Ambiguous column name 'member_mailid'."

Comment: Sorry, I think I had a column doubled up. Please see the edited query.

Comment: Thank You Mr.Preston, So in this final query, Can i get Distinct Member Mail ID's and also COUNT(Member_Mailid) > 3(did more than 3 transactions)...?  Is it possible...?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but I've added another query that could help. If this is still not what you're after, your best option is to add some sample data with an expected result so it's easy to see exactly what you need.